# what's the lowest level way to send data to the device /dev/eth0 (or similar) with c/c++

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, ip, ethernet

I have playing recently with the socket interface on linux and window to send TCP and UDP packets between machines on the same network. Usually, this is done with some socket structure, with methods to open, write data, read data and close it when it's done.

Is there a way to do that without this socket structure? I mean, if I use it, this structure take the data I pass to it, pack it with the protocol headers and send through the network.

If I create the protocol packets and datagrams manually, Do i could use something similar to `cat file.txt > /dev/etho` (or `/dev/wlp5s0` in my case) but using c/c++ to send the data to the other machine on the network?

Comment: You might take a look at [raw sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) or [user space networking](https://www.google.com/search?q=user+space+networking).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I already knew about raw sockets, but still uses sockets, right? I will give a look at this user space networking.

Comment: *"but still uses sockets"* - yes, it is still a file descriptor where you can read and write too. But, accessing `/dev/eth0` like you propose means also you have a file descriptor where you can read and write. Only that you now not only have the ability to do everything but also need to do everything, including making sure that no other application infers with your direct use of the network card. That's what user space network essentially does: one process (and only one process) has full control of the network card instead of the kernel having full control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly open `/dev/eth0`, for a reason that may be obvious if you tried:

```
$ cat /dev/eth0
cat: /dev/eth0: No such file or directory
```

The network devices simply are not represented in the file system the way other hardware devices (such as disks and serial lines) are.

What you can do, as some pointed out in the comments, is use raw sockets. Raw sockets allow you to do just what you want them to: send out packets that are fully formed, that the kernel will output as is, without modifying in any way (TCP checksum offloading non-withstanding).

If you wish to have the other direction, i.e. - have the kernel treat your file descriptor as if it is a network device, you can use the tap/tun interface `/dev/net/tun`. This allows you to create an interface that the kernel treats as if it is an actual ethernet device, which you control what gets "received", and the kernel let's you know what it is sending.